# Can you compile a TS file with webpack separately from Vue application?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, webpack, web-worker

So I have a Vue 3 + Typescript app. `npm run build` of course takes the app and compiles it into the `dist` folder so it can be deployed. I have a web worker typescript file that I would like to be compiled separately so that it ends up in the root of the `dist` folder with the name `worker.js`. Here is what I'm looking for:

```
dist
  |- worker.js
src
  |- worker.ts // This gets compiled to js file in dist folder
```

I tried doing this by using webpack's `DefinePlugin` in my `vue.config.js` like so:

```
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: {
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                entry: `${__dirname}/src/worker.ts`,
                module: {
                    rules: [
                        {
                            test: /worker\.ts$/,
                            use: 'ts-loader',
                            exclude: /node-modules/
                        }
                    ]
                },
                resolve: {
                    extensions: ['.ts']
                },
                output: {
                    filename: 'worker.js',
                    path: `${__dirname}/dist`
                }
            })
        ],
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                vue$: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, `npm run build` just completely ignores the `worker.ts` file and it doesn't show up in the `dist` folder anywhere, not even as a chunk. Any suggestions? Or is what I'm wanting to do even possible? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the desired result using [esbuild](https://esbuild.github.io). Now I can write my web worker in Typescript and use classes and functions from my Vue app. It also compiles lightning fast. I just added the `node ./esbuild.js` command to my `npm run dev` and `npm run build` scripts, and now it compiles to the `public` folder before the Vue app builds. Here is my `esbuild.js` file.

```
const esbuild = require('esbuild')
const { nodeExternalsPlugin } = require('esbuild-node-externals')

const config = {
    entryPoints: ['./src/worker.ts'],
    outfile: 'public/worker.js',
    bundle: true,
    minify: false,
    logLevel: 'silent',
    plugins: [nodeExternalsPlugin()]
}

esbuild.build(config).catch(() => process.exit(1))
```

Let me know if you have any questions, I'd be happy to help anyone out getting this working.